# Can I use Spring-session to my old non-spring project

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-session

I already have old JSP project, but I want to take advantage of spring-session in particularly for SSO. I don't want to convert my old project to completely 'spring' version, because need so much effort to my team.

It's not hard to configure using java config and spring project. Can anybody give walkthrough to do this on my old JSP project?

Comment: Please start doing some code by yourself , then if you got stucked with some exact issue, then someone will be able to  help you. Refer this link for asking proper questions 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I need to learn to write question better. Because I really have no idea how to implement this. But I will do some googling and might be found how to integrate traditional Servlets project with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Session has no required dependencies on any other Spring Project. See the [Hazelcast example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.0.1.RELEASE//samples/hazelcast) for a demonstration of this. In this example, you will not need to bring in any Spring dependencies except Spring Session.

Alternatively, if you want to use Redis based implementation you can use Spring only for creating a SessionRepositoryFilter and nothing else. See the [XML Quick Start](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-xml.html) for a sample.

With either approach you will NOT need to use Spring in the rest of your application to leverage Spring Session.